# Weird shift with \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I have some points i want to draw lines inbetween. Since this repeats quiet a bit, I thought I'd try my hands at a for loop. However there is some weird offset to the whole picture, that gets added in each for loop iteration, that is not intended, and which I do not understand.

First some definitions I'll use in my pictures.

```
\def\l{2}
\def\b{2}
\def\n{3}
\def\delta{(\n-1)*(\l+\b)-\l-2}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{x}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)}
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{y}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)+\l}
}
```

Here is the MWD, that works as intended:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black,above right}]
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
\coordinate (x1) at ({x(1)},1);
\coordinate (y1) at ({y(1)},1);

\coordinate (x2) at ({x(2)},1);
\coordinate (y2) at ({y(2)},1);

\coordinate (x3) at ({x(3)},1);
\coordinate (y3) at ({y(3)},1);

\draw[dotted] (P) -- (x1);
\draw (x1) -- (y1);
\draw[dotted] (y1) -- (P);

\draw[dotted] (P) -- (x2);
\draw (x2) -- (y2);
\draw[dotted] (y2) -- (P);

\draw[dotted] (P) -- (x3);
\draw (x3) -- (y3);
\draw[dotted] (y3) -- (P);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the result:

[image: Intended Result]

Whereas the for-loop version

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black,above right}]
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \coordinate (x) at ({x(\i)},1);
        \coordinate (y) at ({y(\i)},1);
        \draw[dotted] (P) -- (x);
        \draw (x) -- (y);
        \draw[dotted] (y) -- (P);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Produces this:

[image: Weird offset]

My best guess, why this happens, is some weird scope-issue. However i rarely use tikz, so i have no idea, how to fix this/what the actual issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code sniped to complete small compilable document. Also correct all errors ( like `\coordinate (x1) at ({x(1)},1);` ) in your code fragment.

Comment: Try the following: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x2) at (2,-1);
\foreach \i in {0,2,4}
{
\draw (\i,0) coordinate (a\i) -- ++ (1,0) coordinate (b\i);
\draw[dotted] (a\i) -- (x2) (b\i) -- (x2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
`

Comment: Your definitions are ill-advised, to say the least. The names of the functions are almost certainly problematic.

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to use `\pgfmathparse` here? The manual uses `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` very differently *and* recommends using `\pgfmathredeclarefunction` instead.

Comment: Some would consider `\def\delta{(\n-1)*(\l+\b)-\l-2}` a dangerous practice, in particular outside the `tikzpicture` (or other groups). Imagine you would like to typeset a `\delta`. So I'd recommend keeping the definitions local, and using less dangerous names for the macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of trailing spaces at the end. Use

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{x}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)}%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{y}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)+\l}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so weird. do you have any idea, why trailing spaces/new lines would cause this?

Comment: A problem in `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`

Comment: @PlatinTato Henri Menke gave the solution in his comment to my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515863/weird-shift-with-foreach#comment1304391_515874

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to make two loops, the first to define the coordinates, the second to use them.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\l{2}
\def\b{2}
\def\n{3}
\def\delta{(\n-1)*(\l+\b)-\l-2}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{x}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)}
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{y}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{\delta-(#1-1)*(\b+\l)+\l}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black,above right}]
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \coordinate (x\i) at ({x(\i)},1);
        \coordinate (y\i) at ({y(\i)},1);
    }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \draw[dotted] (P) -- (x\i);
        \draw (x\i) -- (y\i);
        \draw[dotted] (y\i) -- (P);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: There are spurious spaces in `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, make your comment an answer.